# How to add checkboxes to each day in this calendar view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, calendar

I am trying to add a simple checkbox feature to each day in my calendar view. It must be inline with the style of the current calendar and when a bool is selected it must be able to save the changes to the database.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My main issue at the moment is the checkboxes that are being selected are not being saved to the db.

**Controller.cs**

```
private F2FW _db = new F2FW();

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CalendarIndex()
    {
        List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
        Project.Models.Calendar calendar = new Project.Models.Calendar();
        calendar.SetDate(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        calendar.View(@"~\Views\Patient\Calendar.cshtml");
        calendar.ViewData.Add("events", events);

        ViewBag.calendar = calendar.Render();

        return View(calendar);
    }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalendarIndex(User user, CalendarArg calArg, int dayCounter, string[] cbx_day, Patient patient, SessionExercise sessionExercise)
        {
            SessionInformation sessiondata = new SessionInformation();
            Session lastsession = db.Sessions.Where(s => s.ActiveUserID == user.UserID).OrderByDescending(e => e.StartedAt).FirstOrDefault();
            calArg.CompletedToday = DateTime.Today;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (calArg.CompletionRequested == false)
                {
                    //do nothing!
                }
                else if (calArg.CompletionRequested == true)
                {
                    if (sessiondata.Completed == true)
                    {
                        if (sessionExercise.FinishedAt == calArg.Past)
                        {
                            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
                            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Completed", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0), Type = Event.EventType.Vacation }); //green
                        }

                    }
                    if (sessiondata.Completed == false)
                    {
                        if (sessionExercise.FinishedAt == calArg.Past)
                        {
                            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
                            events.Add(new Event() { Title = "Exercises Uncompleted", EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0), Type = Event.EventType.Critical }); //red
                        }
                    }
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("CalendarIndex"); // or where ever you want to go
            }
            else
            {
                return View(calArg);
            }
        }
public class Event
{
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime EventDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public EventType Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public enum EventType
    {
        Appointment,
        Meeting,
        Vacation,
        Birthday,
        Personal,
        Critical
    }
}
```

**Model.Calendar.cs**

```
public class Calendar
{
    int _year;
    int _month;
    DateTime _selectedDate;
    string _viewFile = "";
    ViewDataDictionary _viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();

    Func<DateTime, bool, string> _onDayRenderFunc = null;

    public Calendar()
    {
        SetDate(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
    }

    public void SetDate(int year, int month)
    {
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _selectedDate = new DateTime(_year, _month, 1);
    }

    public void SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _selectedDate = new DateTime(_year, _month, day);
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedDate;
        }
    }

    public void OnDayRender(Func<DateTime, bool, string> func)
    {
        _onDayRenderFunc = func;
    }

    public void View(string viewFile)
    {
        _viewFile = viewFile;
    }

    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
    {
        get
        {
            return _viewData;
        }
    }

    public string Render()
    {
        string[] dayNames = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(_year, _month);
        int pYear = _year;
        int pMonth = _month;

        if ((_month - 1) < 1)
        {
            --pYear;
            pMonth = 12;
        }
        else
        {
            --pMonth;
        }

        int daysInPrevMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(pYear, pMonth);

        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(_year, _month, 1);
        int dayPos = (int)d1.DayOfWeek;
        daysInPrevMonth -= dayPos - 1;

        StringBuilder control = new StringBuilder();
        control.Append("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n<thead>\n<tr>\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < dayNames.Length; i++)
        {
            control.Append(string.Format("<th>{0}</th>\n", dayNames[i]));
        }

        control.Append("</thead>\n<tbody>\n");

        int totalDaysInMonth = daysInMonth + dayPos;
        int col = 0;
        int day = 0;
        string cellValue = "";

        for (int idx = 0; idx < totalDaysInMonth; idx++)
        {
            if (col == 0)
            {
                control.Append("<tr>\n");
            }

            if (idx >= dayPos)
            {
                ++day;

                if (_viewFile == "")
                {
                    cellValue = _onDayRenderFunc != null ? _onDayRenderFunc(new DateTime(_year, _month, day), true) : day.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData.Model = new CalendarArg() { Date = new DateTime(_year, _month, day), SelectedDate = _selectedDate, CurrentMonth = true };
                    cellValue = this.Parse(_viewFile);
                }

                control.Append(string.Format("<td data-day=\"{0}\" data-month=\"{1}\" data-year=\"{2}\">{3}</td>\n", day, _month, _year, cellValue));
            }
            else
            {
                if (_viewFile == "")
                {
                    cellValue = _onDayRenderFunc != null ? _onDayRenderFunc(new DateTime(pYear, pMonth, daysInPrevMonth), false) : daysInPrevMonth.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData.Model = new CalendarArg() { Date = new DateTime(pYear, pMonth, daysInPrevMonth), SelectedDate = _selectedDate, CurrentMonth = false };
                    cellValue = this.Parse(_viewFile);
                }

                control.Append(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>\n", cellValue));
                ++daysInPrevMonth;
            }

            if (col == 6)
            {
                control.Append("</tr>\n");
                col = 0;
                continue;
            }
            ++col;
        }

        if (col < 7)
        {
            int nextMonthDay = 1;

            for (int c = col; c < 7; c++)
            {
                if ((_month + 1) > 12)
                {
                    ++_year;
                    _month = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++_month;
                }

                if (_viewFile == "")
                {
                    cellValue = _onDayRenderFunc != null ? _onDayRenderFunc(new DateTime(_year, _month, nextMonthDay), false) : nextMonthDay.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData.Model = new CalendarArg() { Date = new DateTime(_year, _month, nextMonthDay), SelectedDate = _selectedDate, CurrentMonth = false };
                    cellValue = this.Parse(_viewFile);
                }

                control.Append(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>\n", cellValue));
                ++nextMonthDay;
            }

            control.Append("</tr>\n");
        }
        control.Append("</tbody>\n</table>\n");
        return control.ToString();
    }

    private string Parse(string viewFile)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ControllerContext ctx = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext();
            ctx.HttpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

            RazorView view = new RazorView(ctx, viewFile, "", false, null);
            TempDataDictionary tdd = new TempDataDictionary();

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ctx, view, ViewData, tdd, sw);

            view.Render(viewContext, sw);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model.CalendarArg.cs**

```
public class CalendarArg
{
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date  { get; set; }
    public bool CurrentMonth  { get; set; }
    public bool CompletionRequested { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedToday { get; set; }
}
```

**View.CalendarIndex.cshtml**

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #EEE;
    }

        table thead tr th {
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #666;
        }

        table tbody tr td {
            border: 1px solid #EEE;
            width: 14%;
        }

            table tbody tr td .cell1, .cell2 {
                min-height: 150px;
                height: 100%;
            }

            table tbody tr td .selected_day h2 {
                Color: #FFF;
                background-color: #3498DB;
                text-shadow: none;
            }

            table tbody tr td .cell1 {
                background-color: #FFF;
            }

                table tbody tr td .cell1:hover h2 {
                    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #999;
                }

            table tbody tr td .cell2 {
                background-color: #FCFCFC;
            }

                table tbody tr td .cell2 h2 {
                    color: #CCC;
                }

            table tbody tr td h2 {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: normal;
                float: right;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 6px;
                color: #154B67;
                background-color: #EEE;
                display: block;
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
                text-align: center;
                text-shadow: 2px 1px #FFF;
            }

            table tbody tr td .evt {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 10px;
                color: #FFF;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }

            table tbody tr td .clear {
                clear: both;
            }

    .Meeting {
        background-color: #DDD;
        color: #222 !important;
    }

    .Personal {
        background-color: #3498DB;
    }

    .Vacation {
        background-color: #2ECC71;
    }

    .Appointment {
        background-color: #F5AB35;
    }

    .Critical {
        background-color: #F22613;
    }
</style>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.calendar)
```

**View.Calendar.cshtml**

```
    @model Project.Models.CalendarArg
    @{
        CalendarArg calArg = this.Model;
        List<Project.Controllers.Event> events = (List<Project.Controllers.Event>)ViewData["events"];


        string cssClass = calArg.CurrentMonth == true ? "cell1" : "cell2";
    }

    @if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.SelectedDate.Day)
    {
        cssClass += " selected_day";
    }

@if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.Date.Day)
{
    if (DateTime.Now <= calArg.Date)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested, new { @checked = calArg.CompletionRequested });
    }
}

    <div class="@cssClass">
        <h2>@calArg.Date.Day.ToString()</h2>
        <div class="clear"></div>

            @foreach (var evt in events)
            {
                if (evt.EventDate.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") == calArg.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                {
                    <div class="evt @evt.Type.ToString()">@evt.Title</div>
                }
            }
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**

By adding this line of code to `Calendar.cshtl`:

```
@if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.Date.Day)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested, new { @checked = calArg.CompletionRequested }); 
}
```

It surprisingly works, so i guess i'd like to know how to alter the css style sheet in `calendar index` to have the checkboxes flush with the calendar design (i.e. inline with the calendar and not just above it) and how to save changes to the bool to the db.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.ondayrender%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra, thanks.  Are you saying that this can be done from the controller?

Comment: seemingly so yes, using the DayRender event. You could just put <input> tags in there using the add literal in the example... then get their value on post to action.

Comment: can you share your event controller , So i can make sample n check the issue

Comment: and what is events Under 
calendar.ViewData.Add("events", events); its giving me error for this

Comment: I have just updated the code with where i am currently at with it, thanks.

Comment: Just added events too

Comment: What i am currently trying to do is have the events work with the checkboxes (in the controller).  Currently when a box is checked, is doesnt save it to the db.

Comment: from what i can see, CalendarArg is not on the _db.

Comment: @KaushikThanki, sorry i forgot to tag you in my comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have this inside the foreach loop:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested , new { @checked = evt.CompletionRequested });
```

UPDATE:
Answer to your question in comments. Do HttpPost to controller and pass model data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalendarIndex(CalendarArg model)
{
     // Check that model is valid
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // CODE here to update Database
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // or where ever you want to go
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model); // Return back to View, model is not valid
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

If you want to add a class name you can do it like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested , new { @checked = evt.CompletionRequested, @class = "checkbox" });
```

Or you can add css like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
{
      // css when radio button is selected
}

input[type="radio"]
{
      // css when radio button is not selected
}
```

These CSS styles is global so every input element with type radio will get styles.

And when you want to change changes to db context, you need first find the current one from context. Then add true value to CompletionRequested property and then call SaveChanged method from your context. You'r first question was to get checkboxes on your calendarView, not how to save changes to db. That's another question.

Comment: Thanks, but that just throws an exception, the event system isn't what controls the days being populated in the calendar, plus `CompletionRequested` is not a part of `Event` in the controller.

Comment: I have made some progress with your suggesion, i used your line and put it inside this if statement, suprisingly it worked. `@if (calArg.Date.Day == calArg.Date.Day)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CompletionRequested, new { @checked = calArg.CompletionRequested }); 
}` I feel kinda dumb now. How would i go about 1. saving those changes to the db? and 2. putting it into a css class where it is flush with the days in the calendar?

Comment: You would make a HttpPost to controller with data.

Comment: I updated the question with my latest code, still not updating to the db. CalendarArgs has not created a table in the server explorer either.

Comment: Well if you are using EntityFramework with Code-first it should populate table for you. You should create a new question with your database problem